# android use Messenger to communicate between a service and external app

Tags: android, service, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to have a service as part of app A and access the service from app B, using Messenger? Or does one have to directly use AIDL for that?

I suppose I should create a content provider, but I'm trying to keep to a simpler implementation.

Comment: you can have IPC using `Messenger` but you can pass via `Message.obj` only primitive types and `Parcelable`s

Comment: Does that extend to separate apps or only separate processes within an app? I presume the former.

Comment: you can use it in both cases

Comment: btw you can also use low level [IBinder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder) protocol -  `IBinder#transact()` matched by `Binder.onTransact()`

Comment: Yep, thanks for all the clarification.

Comment: sure, your welcome